# Knockout, requirejs and Jasmine test fails

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, jasmine

I've got a knockout component with the following view model:

```
    define(["jquery", "knockout"], function ($, ko) {
    return function () {

        function companySet(value) {
            var self = this;

            self.id = ko.observable(value.id);
            self.name = ko.observable(value.name);
            self.numberOfCompanies = ko.observable(value.numberOfCompanies);
            self.numberOfEmployees = ko.observable(value.numberOfEmployees);
        }

        function companySetList() {
            var self = this;

            self.companySets = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.getCompanySets = function() {
                self.companySets.removeAll();

                $.getJSON("/companysets", function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            self.companySets.push(new companySet(value));
                        });
                    });
            };
        }

        this.viewModel = new companySetList();
        this.viewModel.getCompanySets();
    };
});
```

My specs file looks like this;

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {

    describe("Company Set List Tests", function () {

        beforeEach(function(){
            jasmine.Ajax.install();
        })

        afterEach(function(){
            jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
        })

        describe("when loaded", function () {

            it("it should load the company sets", function () {
                require(["app/files/company-set-list"]);
                var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
                expect(request.method).toBe("GET");
                expect(request.url).toBe("/companysets");
            });

        });

        describe("Testing ajax stuff", function(){

            it("just test the friggen call", function(){
                $.getJSON("/test", function(){});
                expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe("/test");
            });

        });
    });
});
```

The company-set-list is loaded, but it does not call the getCompanySets method. Thus, I cannot get the test to work. When the loaded as part of the knockout component, the company-set-list view model works as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your test doesn't appear to construct an instance of your view model?  I assume that the `require` call should have a return value that's being instantiated?

Comment: I've tried a number of ways to have require pull in that module... The better question is how do I test the $.getJSON call in the view model with Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to James Thorpe. It's the simple things. I wasn't creating an instance of the view model, so the $.getJSON call was never being fired. Here's the updated spec file...

`
define(["jquery", "app/files/company-set-list"], function ($, sut) {

```
describe("Company Set List Tests", function () {

    beforeEach(function(){
        jasmine.Ajax.install();
        this.instance = new sut();
    })

    afterEach(function(){
        jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
    })

    describe("when loaded", function () {

        it("it should load the company sets", function () {
            var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
            expect(request.method).toBe("GET");
            expect(request.url).toBe("/companysets");
        });

    });

    describe("Testing ajax stuff", function(){

        it("just test the friggen call", function(){
            $.getJSON("/true", function(){});
            expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe("/true");
        });

    });
});
```

});
`

Comment: Not sure what's up with the oddball formatting... :|